# A basic problem on random series/ law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Consider the following two statements :

i) Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are independent and identically distributed and $E[X_1^-] < \infty, E[X_1^+] = \infty$. Then $n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k \to \infty$ with probability $1$.

ii) Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are independent and identically distributed and $E[|X_1|] = \infty$. It can be proved that $\sup_{n}n^{-1}|\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k| = \infty$ w.p.$1$.

In a problem it is asked to compare these two statements. What is the meaning of it ?

Answer (score 0):

These two statements give the behavior of $M_n:=S_n/n$ when $X_1$ is not integrable. 
This means that *at least one* of the random variables $X_1^+$ or $X_1^-$ is not integrable.

When both are non integrable, the best we can say is that the supremum of the $|M_n|$'s is infinite almost everywhere.

But if we know that $X_1^-$ has a finite expectation, we can say more, namely, $M_n\to+\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ because for each integer $M$ and almost every $\omega$, 
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^nX_j(\omega)\geqslant\mathbb E[X_1^+\chi_{\{X_1^+\leqslant M\}}]-\mathbb E[X_1^-].$$

[Here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~erickson/psordvi/slln.pdf) are conditions to determine the conclusion we can expect.